# Carbon ROM update fails: Failed to setup flash. Clean /cache and retry

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms

I try to update to the latest Carbon ROM. The check is successful, but the flash fails with "Failed to setup flash. Clean /cache and retry."

[image]

I already went to Settings > System > System Updates > Settings (right-top corner) > Clean update files [Delete existing update files to force downloading full update]

and tried the update again without success. Happens the first time for me, last update was just recently on 8. May without problems.

I also just tried going in Recovery Mode > Team Win Recovery Project > Wipe > Advanced Wipe > select Cache > Wipe. But the problem still remains after the reboot.

Comment: Did you try cleaning cache from the recovery?

Comment: I just tried it. Went in Recovery  Mode > Team Win Recovery Project > Wipe > Advanced Wipe > select Cache > Wipe. But the problem remains after the reboot.